# Invoking .map() on an infinite stream?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream, functional-interface

According to Javadocs for SE 8 Stream.map() does the following

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

However, a book I'm reading (*Learning Network Programming with Java*, Richard M. Reese) on networking implements roughly the following code snippet in an echo server.

```
Supplier<String> inputLine = () -> {
    try {
        return br.readLine();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
};

Stream.generate(inputLine).map((msg) -> {
    System.out.println("Recieved: " + (msg == null ? "end of stream" : msg));
    out.println("echo: " + msg);
    return msg;
}).allMatch((msg) -> msg != null);
```

This is supposed to be a functional way to accomplish getting user input to print to the socket input stream. It works as intended, but I don't quite understand how. Is it because map knows the stream is infinite so it lazily executes as new stream tokens become available? It seems like adding something to a collection currently being iterated over by map is a little black magick. Could someone please help me understand what is going on behind the scenes?

---

Here is how I restated this in order to avoid the confusing map usage. I believe the author was trying to avoid an infinite loop since you can't break out of a forEach.

```
Stream.generate(inputLine).allMatch((msg) -> {
        boolean alive = msg != null;
        System.out.println("Recieved: " + (alive ? msg : "end of stream"));
        out.println("echo: " + msg);

        return alive;
});
```

Comment: Streams are always lazy. However, it's sort of jarring to see side effects used in `map` like this.

Comment: They should be using `peek` instead of `map` here. Using `map` like this is fairly weird.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by 'adding something to a collection'? I don't think there are any collections used in this code.

Comment: @Radiodef no, peek isn't really meant for this either, "This method exists mainly to support debugging". A plain old for loop would be a much less weird way to write this.

Comment: @Radiodef I just tried it with forEach. The problem is that you can't do a break in a forEach loop. This causes an unbreakable infinite loop to be set off. I am about to update OP with solution I found.

Comment: @tdct I guess it would actually be `.takeWhile(Objects::nonNull).forEach(...)` instead of using `filter`. (Though, in general, I agree with Andy that a loop is actually better here.)

Comment: Yes for any wondering why write it like this, it was given to highlight that it's possible to use streams functionally to solve problems, sometimes more effeciently. The first implementation of this in the book was regular old loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams are lazy. Think of them as workers in a chain that pass buckets to each other. The laziness is in the fact that they will only ask the worker behind them for the next bucket if the worker in front of them asks them for it.

So it's best to think about this as `allMatch` - being a final action, thus eager - asking the `map` stream for the next item, and the `map` stream asking the `generate` stream for the next item, and the `generate` stream going to its supplier, and providing that item as soon as it arrives.

It stops when `allMatch` stops asking for items. And it does so when it knows the answer. Are all items in this stream not null? As soon as the `allMatch` receives an item that is null, it knows the answer is `false`, and will finish and not ask for any more items. Because the stream is infinite, it will not stop otherwise.

So you have two factors causing this to work the way it work - one is `allMatch` asking eagerly for the next item (as long as the previous ones weren't null), and the `generate` stream that - in order to supply that next item - may need to wait for the supplier that waits for the user to send more input.

But it should be said that `map` shouldn't have been used here. There should not be side effects in `map` - it should be used for mapping an item of one type to an item of another type. I think this example was used only as a study aid. The much simpler and straightforward way would be to use [`BufferedReader`'s method `lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) which gives you a finite `Stream` of the lines coming from the buffered reader.

Comment: Is there any method you might use instead of map to achieve the same result in a functional way? I believe forEach is a terminal operation. So you should be able to use a forEach with a conditional break to achieve this in a more clear way.

Comment: No, it would not work with `forEach` because there is no way to stop it, except an exception. The whole trick is based on the fact that `allMatch` can be stopped based on the items it receives. You could use `peek` instead of `map`, but in any case, strictly speaking, if there are side effects, it's not really functional.

Comment: Using `peek` instead of `map` wouldn’t change the fact that this code abuses implementation details which are not guaranteed. Not only is `map` not guaranteed to process only lines up to the first `null`, it is not guaranteed to process them in order. What makes matters worse, is that `Stream.generate` produces an *unordered* stream, so even Java 9‘s `Stream.generate(…).takeWhile(…)` is not guaranteed to do the desired thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - `Stream`s are setup lazily until and unless you perform a terminal operation (final action) on the `Stream`. Or simpler:

*For as long as the operations on your stream return another Stream, you do not have a terminal operation, and you keep on chaining until you have something returning anything other than a Stream, including void.*

This makes sense, as to be able to return anything other than a Stream, the operations earlier in your stream will need to be evaluated to actually be able to provide the data.

In this case, and as per documentation, [`allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) returns a `boolean`, and thus final execution of your stream is required to calculate that boolean. This is the point also where you provide a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) limiting your resulting `Stream`.

Also note that in the documentation it states:

> This is a [short-circuiting terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

Follow that link for more information on those terminal operations, but a terminal operation basically means that it will actually execute the operation. Additionally, the limiting of your infinite stream is the 'short-circuiting' aspect of that method.

Comment: Thank you. "For as long as methods you executes keep on returning another stream, you just keep on lazily defining what you intend to do by chaining all your operations." That is a perfect answer to my question really clears everything up for me! Had to checkmark realskeptic because he went more in depth but I very much appreciate this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two the most relevant sentences of the [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) documentation. The snippet you provided is a perfect example of these working together:

- [`Stream::generate(Supplier<T> s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) says that it returns:

  > Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is generated by the provided `Supplier`.
- [3rd dot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) of Stream package documentation:

  > Laziness-seeking. Many stream operations, such as filtering, mapping, or duplicate removal, can be implemented lazily, exposing opportunities for optimization. For example, "find the first String with three consecutive vowels" need not examine all the input strings. Stream operations are divided into intermediate (Stream-producing) operations and terminal (value- or side-effect-producing) operations. Intermediate operations are always lazy.

In a shortcut, this generated stream await the further elements until the terminal operation is reached. As long as the execution inside the supplied [`Supplier<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), the stream pipeline continues.

As an example, if you provide the following `Supplier`, the execution has no chance to stop and will continue infinitely:

```
Supplier<String> inputLine = () -> {
    return "Hello world";
};
```